# Why am I getting "an error occurred submitting the question" when posting a question?

Tags: support, quality-filter

I am trying to ask the below question with tags 'tsql, sql-server2008-r2, query-optimization' and the title *query runs slow* but Stack Overflow won't accept it. Instead, it shows the error message:

> an error occurred submitting the question

What is wrong - am I blocked or something?

> I have the below query to update the final report table which will be used creating a report file.
>
> ```
> select [Collateral ID], [DataDate], 
>        [Cif], [Collateral Category],
>        [Expiry Date], [Realizable Amount], [Currency],
>        [Classification of Property], [Market Value],
>        [Country],[CB_Guarantor], [CB_Guarantee]
> from v0_AccountSecuritiesBASEL_III
>     WHERE
>         ((DataDate)='2014-04-30')
>         and [Collateral ID] NOT IN (Select [Collateral ID] 
>         from [dbo].[v1_AccountSecuritiesBASEL_III])
> ```
>
> If I run it with only the date restriction it’s pretty fast (1-2 seconds), but the restriction on the [Collateral ID] from the view `v1_AccountSecuritiesBASEL_III` is killing it.
>
> The number of records involved isn't crazy, we're talking about 10-20,000 rows and the last restriction only prevents about 27 records being included as they are added seperately (after having been split into 2 records making a total of 54 that need to be checked)
>
> Is there a way to optimize this that I haven’t considered?

Comment: That's a truly horrible title. What error message are you getting.

Comment: it just says 'an error occurred submitting the question' - I have tried other titles such as 'query optimization' and the same message appears

Comment: @Philip: Are you behind a proxy? Proxies can often block posts which contain SQL.

Comment: Generally speaking an error message resulting from the "system" would have been slightly more descriptive message.  I believe "an error submitting the quuestion" error is a client side message, and often occurs when there is a problem actually communicating with the server.  You should check your correction.  An overly aggressive firewall might be to blame.

Comment: amazing, as soon as I reduced the amount of words, it was accepted ... I noticed something similar on SQL Server Central and MSDN Twechnet recently, perhaps the software checking what I do on the internet at work is to blame!

Comment: @OurManinBananas I don't think it is a word related issue. I believe it is a temporary error. I got this error today and tried to submit the question again after some time after which it was accepted.